# why I got Error during rendering of page item P3_NATIONALITY?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to SELECT nationality in ARABIC name for list of value when open ARABIC system
and SELECT nationality in ENGLISH name when open English language system but I got this error
when open the page

"Error during rendering of page item P3_NATIONALITY.
Technical Info (only available for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_FORM.UNHANDLED_ERROR
ora_sqlcode: -6502
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value"

This is the LIST OF VALUE code :

```
select CASE WHEN APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG = 'ar-ae' 
              THEN SYS_CODES.ITEM_DESC_A 
            ELSE SYS_CODES.ITEM_DESC_E 
            END ,
    SYS_CODES.ITEM_NO as ITEM_NO 
 from SYS_CODES
 WHERE TABLE_NO = 108 
 AND ITEM_NO > 0
 AND HOSPITAL_NO = 1;
```

this is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE "SYS_CODES" 
   (    "HOSPITAL_NO" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "TABLE_NO" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "SUB_TABLE_NO" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "ITEM_NO" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "ITEM_DESC_A" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ITEM_DESC_E" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "VALUE_1" VARCHAR2(8), 
    "VALUE_2" VARCHAR2(8), 
    "PROTECT" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_UPDATE_DATE" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "LAST_UPDATE_COUNT" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "LAST_UPDATE_USER" VARCHAR2(8), 
    "LAST_UPDATE_TRANSACTION" VARCHAR2(1), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("HOSPITAL_NO", "TABLE_NO", "SUB_TABLE_NO", "ITEM_NO")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   ) ;
```

I used CASE WHEN before to read ARABIC and ENGLISH names in dynamic menu list and its working why in list of value for page item its give this error when open the page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I need to select the display Item for list of values

```
select CASE WHEN APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG = 'ar-ae' 
              THEN SYS_CODES.ITEM_DESC_A 
            ELSE SYS_CODES.ITEM_DESC_E 
            END as ITEM_DESC,
    SYS_CODES.ITEM_NO as ITEM_NO 
 from SYS_CODES
 WHERE TABLE_NO = 108 
 AND ITEM_NO > 0
 AND HOSPITAL_NO = 1;
```

I need to select in column mapping

```
Return Item = ITEM_NO 

Display = ITEM_DESC
```

and this solved the issue and show ARABIC and ENGLISH names correct .

Answer (score 0):

In my case was caused by a button attribute list being too long for its taste:
#BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES# text-align: left !important;